# How could i make a server side application which stores data in client side database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ms-access, database-connection

I am building an asp.net website which needs a database, but the requirements are such that i shall not store the data on the server. So i need help on how to store the data of a server side asp.net website on a client side database file.
Means a web app interacting with a client side database file which could also be stored in a flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the [HTML5 Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

Also you may reado: [how to store data to database in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865980/how-to-store-data-to-database-in-html5)

and search on internet for more.